# Write to a file from a C++ ROS node?

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is there a way to write to a file from the C++ source of a ROS node? I know that I can write directly to a .bag file, however I would like to be able to write to my own file formats (i.e. directly to a CSV rather than having to export a CSV from rxbag, etc).

I tried this from within the C++ of a node:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
```

With the above code, the program executes just fine but I can't find "example.txt" anywhere on the file system. Does ROS just ignore this operation, or put the file somewhere I can't seem to find?

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11642/write-to-a-file-from-a-c++-ros-node?/) by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 353 on 2011-10-22

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should put in the whole path for where you want the file to be written.

```
myfile.open("/home/user/example.txt")
```

That way the file is always created in /home/user/ and not the directory ros runs the program from.

---

Originally posted by [thericcer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1261/thericcer/) with karma: 151 on 2011-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-09-27**:
I was writing some STL files (output from nodes that worked with PCL and converted point clouds to meshes). I've noticed that when you don't give the full path but just the file name (example: `my_mesh.stl`) the file is written into `.ros` (the hidden folder inside the user's `/home`. Weird...

**Comment by [xingxiajie](https://answers.ros.org/users/41485/xingxiajie/) on 2019-05-11**:
like the comment above, i found my files in the hidden folder .ros,

**Comment by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on 2019-12-12**:
is it possible to instead of passing the whole path to use something like $(find package)/data/example.txt?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tried your example code but changed it to:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
.
.
.
ofstream myfile("example.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
```

Edit: Cleaning up thanks to @joq's comment.

Using `rosrun` this created and wrote to "example.txt" in the directory that I ran the node from. I tried running from several different directories, and each time the file "example.txt" showed up in the directory I was in, and had nothing to do with the location of the node binary.

Using `roslaunch` this created and wrote "example.txt" in `~/.ros` no matter which directory I run the `roslaunch` command from.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2011-10-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-10-22**:
That works with `rosrun` but not `roslaunch`.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-03**:
Actually it shows up in whatever ROS_HOME is set to and defaults to ~/.ros.